# Compile .jade to .html in emacs

Tags: html, emacs, pug

I'm using [this](https://github.com/brianc/jade-mode) mode in emacs for .jade files. The atom editor converts .jade files to .html when saving, I wonder if emacs can do the same thing?

Thanks,

Oliver

Comment: Maybe speak about this with the mode's author in a new issue, so he could add an option ?

Comment: @Ehvince Thanks, I have logged an issue: https://github.com/brianc/jade-mode/issues/69

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, just put this in your `.emacs`:

```
(defun compile-jade ()
  (when (eq major-mode 'jade-mode)
    (shell-command (format "jade %s" buffer-file-name))))

(add-hook 'after-save-hook 'compile-jade)
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm now trying to do this for sass. The command line syntax would be this: "sass -t expanded foo.sass foo.css". My current attempt doesn't work: (shell-command (format "sass -t expanded %s %s" buffer-file-name file-name-sans-extension)). "file-name-sans-extension" is unknown.

Comment: Try `(format "sass -t expanded %s %s" buffer-file-name (file-name-sans-extension buffer-file-name))`. file-name-sans-extension is a function that removes extensions, not a variable.